# Getting overall status on joint table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, the first table `tbl_jobs` let's say is a job table contains the jobs, 
the second table `tbl_job_steps` contains the steps of the jobs stored in first tale.
In the `tbl_job_steps` table there is a `status` column where the status of that particular step is stored.

There can be three status values:

```
0 - invalid 
1 - working
2 - done
```

tbl_jobs

```
  id |         desc        |  
   1 |  firs description   | 
   2 |  second description | 
   3 |  third description  |
```

tbl_job_steps

```
 id | job_id |         desc          | status | 
  1 |      1 | 1. step of first job  |      0 |
  2 |      1 | 2. step of first job  |      1 |
  3 |      1 | 3. step of first job  |      2 |
  4 |      1 | 4. step of first job  |      2 |
  5 |      2 | 1. step of second job |      0 |
  6 |      2 | 2. step of second job |      2 |
```

So I need to get the status of the overall job somehow by selecting the jobs from the `tbl_jobs` and joining the `tbl_job_steps`.

The overall status can be the same as steps statuses:

```
0 - invalid if all steps are invalid
1 - working if one ore more steps status is working
2 - done if all steps are done or some invalid.
```

How to go about this problem?

```
SELECT j.id, j.desc, (here goes the part I'm missing) AS job_status 
    FROM tbl_jobs AS j
       LEFT JOIN tbl_job_steps AS js ON js.job_id = j.id
```

Comment: Will you explain what *the status of the overall job* is?

Comment: Added overall status description to the question

Comment: There is a case like the ids 5 and 6. What would be the overall status for this?

Comment: For the 2. job the overall status needs to be 2-DONE

Comment: Then *done if all steps are done* is not correct. Edit the requirement to cover all cases.

Comment: See my edited answer. I'm not sure that your requirement covers all the cases...

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by job and use a CASE expression to return the overall status:

```
SELECT j.id, j.desc,
       CASE 
         WHEN MAX(js.status) = 0 THEN 0
         WHEN SUM(js.status = 1) > 0 THEN 1
         WHEN MAX(js.status) = 2 THEN 2
       END job_status 
FROM tbl_jobs AS j LEFT JOIN tbl_job_steps AS js 
ON js.job_id = j.id
GROUP BY j.id, j.desc
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uEmBX979VmfK6dV5onRj8o/3).

or simpler:

```
SELECT j.id, j.desc,
       CASE 
         WHEN SUM(js.status = 1) > 0 THEN 1
         ELSE MAX(js.status)
       END job_status 
FROM tbl_jobs AS j LEFT JOIN tbl_job_steps AS js 
ON js.job_id = j.id
GROUP BY j.id, j.desc
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uEmBX979VmfK6dV5onRj8o/5).

Results:

```
| id  | desc               | job_status |
| --- | ------------------ | ---------- |
| 1   | firs description   | 1          |
| 2   | second description | 2          |
| 3   | third description  | null       |
```